# What this sentence mean? "the spell of time"

Tags: phrase-meaning

The sentence in which I've seen this usage is below.

> Thus, the style quotient of skirts has evolved over **the spell of time**.

Comment: mic's answer is correct, but you should note that "the spell of time" is very unusual-sounding.  Maybe it was intended to be poetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Spell" means something like "period".
There could be a "hot spell" in summer, or a "cold spell" in winter.

In your example, you could simply say "... has evolved over time", but adding "the spell of" puts some touch of poetry to the sentence.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I would like to know what the problem with usage "style quotient".

Comment: @PraveenL: Sorry for adding confusion.There's no problem with "style quotient" - it just sounds unfamiliar to me (not a native speaker).